# Monotouch: understand the delegate mechanism pattern

Tags: delegates, xamarin.ios, uipopovercontroller

I didin't completely understand the delegate mechanism in monotouch. Can anyone help me to understand this concept?

The question is simple. I'll try to map what I've done in Objective C in Monotouch.

For example, suppose I've creating a `UIPopoverController` in Objective C inside `MyController`. In Objective C the code is the following:

```
@interface MyController : UIViewController <UIPopoverControllerDelegate> {
    // ...
}
// ...
@end
```

Inside `MyController` I can istantiate a `UIPopoverController` like the following:

```
UIPopoverController *popover = // ...
popover.delegate = self;
```

and finally methods used in the delegate.

So, what about Monotouch?

Through this code I can istantiate the `UIPopoverController` inside `MyController` class that extends `UIViewController` inside a specific TouchUpInside event handler:

```
popover = new UIPopoverController(new CustomController());
popover.PopoverContentSize = new SizeF(200f, 200f);
popover.PresentFromRect(button.Frame, containerForButtonView, UIPopoverArrowDirection.Left, true);
```

P.S. An important aspect is to put popover reference as a member class and not as a local variable inside the handler because the monotouch GC works well!!!

Thank you in advance.

Comment: My first solution works. I've implemented a CustomPopoverController that extends UIPopoverControllerDelegate. Then I've add as popover.delegate an instance of that controller. Is it possible to make as the delegate **MyController** or **CustomController**?

Comment: How did you solution does look like? The only events I can see are `DidDismiss` and `WillReposition` ... Not that much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This really has more to do with C# than MonoTouch itself. In MonoTouch, `UIPopoverControllerDelegate` is a class, and C# doesn't allow multiple inheritance, so you can't translate code one to one with Obj-C. There's an easier way out though (code below compiles, but obviously doesn't work):

```
public class MyController: UIViewController {
        public void mymethod(){
            var popover = new UIPopoverController();
            popover.DidDismiss += HandlePopoverDidDismiss;
            popover.PopoverContentSize = new SizeF(200f, 200f);
            popover.PresentFromRect(button.Frame, containerForButtonView, UIPopoverArrowDirection.Left, true);
        }

        void HandlePopoverDidDismiss (object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Working!");
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, you can add an event handler to to the `DidDismiss` event in the popover, which will do what you want. In general, all events that in Obj-C are handled by the delegate in all controls can be used this way. You can also write the method inline, like this:

```
popover.DidDismiss += delegate {
    //dosomething
};
```

Hope this is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't answer your question specific to your `UIPopovercontroller` I think you will find [this link from the Monotouch Docs useful.](http://monotouch.net/Documentation/API_Design#Delegates) It explains the differences between Objective-C delegates and C# delegates with relation to Monotouch. With regards to your specific problem, I havent got time to whip up a quick test case to understand it fully but figured I'd post that link so you've got something to read in the mean time!